# PDO: select fetch last columns as NULL

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, velocis-rds

when i select data from ODBC with PDO (in PHP) some columns are fetched as NULL, but in database data exists. Where i execute same query with odbc_* functions it works fine.

Here is code i using

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE rowid = 123456";
$connection = odbc_connect("Velocis RDS", $usr, $pwd);
$result = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
while ($data = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
  print_r($data);
}
```

With this all columns are fetched correctly :

```
$connection = new PDO("odbc:Velocis RDS", $usr, $pwd);
$stmt = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE rowid = 123456");
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
```

with this code last 9 columns are fetched as NULL. There is nothing special with this columns. It contains text or numbers.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the exact same issue with a different type of database where the *id* field worked but the others returned null via `pdo_odbc` and worked 100% with `odbc`.  After a lot of research I came across a PHP Bug report with similar issue (Bug#61573) but paved the way to for me to figure out a fix.

---

Try type casting the fields to `VARCHAR`.  This worked for me.  The issue is that `pdo_odbc` does not work with several types that `odbc` can.

---

For reference or if still needed please include the PHP version and table schema as these are important to figure out fixes.  :)